# Spacing objects evenly in a tabular

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm trying to make it so each box is evenly spaced within the tabular environment.

[image]

Any ideas? With thanks,
Wendy

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawdie}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5em,y=5em,3]
  \draw[thick, rounded corners=0.5,line hidden] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
} 


\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\drawdie\hspace{1cm}&\hspace{1cm}\drawdie\\
&\\
\hline 
&\\
\drawdie\hspace{1cm}&\hspace{1cm}\drawdie
\end{tabular}\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code generates the following error message on my system (MacOS 14.3.1, MacTeX2023 with all updates applied): `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/3' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` Please fix.

Comment: Fix the errors, you dont need any of the options of tikzpicture, and use `\hspace*{1cm}`.

Comment: Sorry about the errors, \hspace* worked perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using \hspace*{1cm} works perfectly